# Recuperar valor de select com VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

eu tenho um formulário e gostaria que no campo (que é um select) retornasse (selecionado) o valor marcado anteriormente.

Ex: se meu selecionado for vazio, o `select` vai mostrar os valores normalmente (1, 2, 3, 4). Caso, ele possua valor, meu `select` mostrará todos os valores, porem irá vir com o valor 2 selecionado já.

```
<select v-model="item" style="height: 40px;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>


data(){
   return{
      item: ''
   }
},
mounted(){
   this.api()
},
methods: {
   api(){
      axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
         this.item = response.data.select  
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com _"o valor marcado anteriormente"_? Queres dizer que isso está na base de dados? ou gravado nalgum lado?

Comment: @Sergio sim, isso é preenchido no item, ai caso venha da base marcado, ele preenche no item, se vir vazio da base, ele irá manter o item vazio.

Comment: Ok, e como passas os dados do servidor para o JavaScript?

Comment: @Sergio Atualizei o codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal era teres essas `option` a serem geradas pelo template, assim é fácil verificar se a `option` a ser gerada é aquela que deve ser escolhida.

Algo assim:

```
<select v-model="item" style="height: 40px;">
    <option 
       v-for"option in options" 
       selected="{{option == item}}"
    >
    {{option}}
    </option>
</select>


data(){
   return{
      item: '',
      options: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
   }
},
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu :D uma pergunta, você não tem nenhum Curso de JS por ai? ou livro? rsrs Abraços

Comment: @RafaelAugusto por aqui aprende-se muito, exato como tu fizeste :)

Comment: Em teoria, o `v-model` no select devia dar conta de marcar o item atual.

Comment: @bfavaretto será? mesmo que as "option" estejam por extenso?

Comment: [Sim](https://jsfiddle.net/2ugytxzq/)

Comment: @RafaelAugusto o @bfavaretto tem razão. Na verdade o teu código devia funcionar. Podes verificar se será um problema de estares a dar numeros ao `v-model` quando ele usa strings para comparar?

Comment: Eu acho que o problema deve estar na resposta da API. Mas precisaria ver o código real, acho que o exemplo da pergunta não é o real. A começar pela url que é usada mas não definida.